# How much artificial gravity could create a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

In my world, people have powers based on the four fundamental forces.

One of my characters can generate spontaneous gravity to crush his opponents. He's also resistant to his own power (so I ignore his own mass).

I want to create a twist where he breaks his limit and generates a black hole. How many "g" should I put?

- The size of the black hole may varies (according to the drama I need to create). Let's take the two following scenarios A- Ten meters diameter (melee combat) B- Two hundreds and fifty meters diameters (let's rip battleships combat)
- The gravitational field he generates his constant (eg. 10 g everywhere). The character's mass doesn't count. The gravity don't crush people on him, but on the ground. It's more like an added g to the environment.

Comment: How much *natural* gravity is required to make a black hole?  I bet Google knows!!

Comment: With relativistic effects, things get really complicated really quickly. I suspect there is no value for "G" that is set in stone, but rather a lambda equation based on the amount of mass and the volume it is being compessed into. The good news is that a black hole that small is likely to dissipate quickly due to Hawking radiation. The bad news is that the math is beyond me, which is why this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: G is a gravitational constant. You’re thinking of g (acceleration measured in multiples of 9.8m/s/s, not to be confused with g for grams) or possibly f_g which is force due to gravity.

Comment: I use G (earth = 1 G) so readers can follow easily the power curve. I've search on Google and didn't found anything except for mass and singularity so it's hard for me to evaluate. If I ignore mass and singularity (since I consider the power optimize it) I need a G value.

Comment: With relativistic effects, the "G" value is not meaningful.  Black holes are a relativistic effect, and not subject to analysis by Newtonian mechanics

Comment: But since a black hole his a gravitational callapse, his there a "bridge concept" I could use to explain the power create a black hole ?

Comment: How big a black hole?  A black hole exists when the escape velocity is higher than the speed of light.  The escape velocity decreases with the square of the distance between the centers of mass.  So we need to know the distance to calculate an appropriate mass-equivalent acceleration.

Comment: Its going to be very tricky. I assume you found this site:http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/blkhol.html? Anyway, as your character pushes matter together, it'll start a fusion reaction that prevents collapse (and be quite annoying for nearby people), then as you push it further neutrons will prevent collapse (not sure how or if it will apply here). Then as you push it even harder you overcome these forces and a Black hole is created. According to Film Theory (not the best source) a human mass black-hole would be strong enough to suck in nearby mass until it devours the earth.

Comment: @EliGauthier: you misunderstand: my issue was that capital G is not the same as small g. Small g is one way to say ‘the gravitational force you feel at sea level on Earth’. Big G is a completely different thing.

Comment: @Demigan What would be the effect of a fusion reaction in such a case? Is it equivalent to what happens in a fusion reactor? (It could be an intermediary state of his power so I find it interesting).

Comment: @JoeBloggs ok I understand. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Brythan The size of the black hole may varies (according to the drama I need to create). Let's take the two following scenarios A- Ten meters diameter (melee combat) B- Two hundreds and fifty meters diameters (let's rip battleships combat)

Comment: As for an answer, it should contain something like this formula: F=(G*m1*m2)/r^2. Where G is the earths gravity acceleration. I guess that you can rewrite it to G*X=(F*R^2)/(m1*m2), where the X will be the amount of earth gravitational constants you need to achieve it. I read that with up to 3 solar masses (2*10^30Kg per solar mass) the fusion/neutron thing keeps it from collapsing until those run out. So if you use higher solar masses you should be OK I think but dont pin me on it.

Comment: @EliGauthier  Don't tell me that.  Put it in the question so that everyone can see it, not just people who read the comments.

Comment: The effect of the fusion would be just that: enough heat and energy are together to force fusion, which will release energy like the Sun does. One caveat I just thought off: the Sun does not have enough energy/weight to cause fusion, only because of quantum movement and having lots and lots of mass does our Sun achieve this as matter accidentally tunnels into eachother. So perhaps you would be OK if the mass is small and no quantum weirdness happens.

Comment: @Demigan: This is exactly what I was talking about: In that equation G is the [*gravitational constant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) not the force felt at sea level on earth due to gravity. They are very, *very* different things.

Comment: @Demigan  The `G` in that equation is not Earth's gravity acceleration.  It's the gravitation constant (6.67408 × 10-11 m3 kg-1 s-2).  `F` in that equation is equal to `mg`, where `m` is the mass that is not the Earth's mass.  So $g_E = \frac{G*m_E}{r_E^2} $

Comment: @Brythan I stand corrected

Comment: Crushing the entire earth would give you a black hole the size of a marble (8.86mm). The gravity at its surface (to the extent that even makes sense, which isn't very much as the comments above mention) would be 5x10^17 g, so (presumably) it would take at least that much force to create it. You—and your readers—can't even imagine that properly. Ignoring relativity (among other things), that means if I dropped something from about waist height (1m), it would hit the ground going over the speed of light.  Either give up on "black hole" or give up on a realistic representation.

Answer (score 11):

The formula for [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) is

$$v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2Gm}{r}}$$

$v_e$ is the escape velocity.

$G$ is the gravitational constant, approximately equal to $6.67×10^{−11} m^3\cdot {kg}^{−1}\cdot s^{−2}$.

$m$ is the mass of the object from which we are trying to escape (the black hole).

$r$ is the distance between that object and the object that is trying to escape.

The formula for the magnitude of [gravitational acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration) is

$$g = \frac{Gm}{r^2}$$

$g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Now, we know $G$ (a constant), $v_e$ (greater than the speed of light), and $r$ (either 10 or 250 meters:  given in your question).  We do not know $g$, although we know that it is at most fifteen times the Earth's acceleration due to gravity at sea level.  We do not know $m$.

So let's rewrite the first equation in terms of $m$.

$$m = \frac{{v_e}^2r}{2G}$$

Now we substitute that into the second equation.

$$g = \frac{{v_e}^2}{2r}$$

Now, substitute in the speed of light and the distance.  We'll use 10 meters as the distance.

$$g = 4.5\cdot 10^{15} \frac{m}{s^2}$$

That's roughly $4.5\cdot 10^{14}g_E$, where $g_E$ is the acceleration due to gravity at sea level on the Earth.  That's much higher than fifteen.

We can calculate things the other way.  A 15g acceleration at the event horizon of a black hole implies a black hole that is less than $3\cdot 10^{-13}$ meters in size.  This is tiny.  For comparison, a proton is about $10^{-15}$ meters.  So this is bigger than a nucleus but a lot smaller than an [atom](https://education.jlab.org/qa/how-much-of-an-atom-is-empty-space.html).

I have ignored relativistic effects, but I don't think they would matter much.  We start in the same inertial frame.  There might be a black hole, but it would be smaller than an atom.

You could improve on this by making the initial acceleration dependent on distance as well.  For example, if he could make an acceleration equal to fifteen g at a distance of ten meters from the center of attraction, then it would be a lot larger at one meter and larger still at one millimeter.

Part of the confusion may be that a black hole still has gravitational attraction outside its event horizon.  The event horizon is the place where the black hole won't release light.  But you'd have to moving close to the speed of light to escape if you came close to the event horizon.

Your fifteen g of acceleration is confusing in that it doesn't mention the distance to the center of attraction.  The presumption is that it is being created at the accelerated object.  But gravity doesn't work that way.  It accelerates towards a center of mass somewhere.

It might make more sense to think of him as always creating a black hole.  The stronger he gets, the farther away that he can pull an object.  The black hole might get visible at sufficient strength.

For example, consider if he can create a fifteen g acceleration at 250 meters from the point of attraction.

Let 250 meters be $d$ and solve the second equation for $m$.

$$m = \frac{gd^2}{G}$$

Now solve the first equation for $r$.

$$r = \frac{2Gm}{v_e^2}$$

Substitute

$$r = \frac{2gd^2}{c^2}$$

$c$ is the velocity of light.

This gives us about a $10^-10$ meters black hole.  That's similar to the size of an atom, so still far below visibility.

**TL;DR**:  fifteen g is not enough to make a visible black hole, even operating at a distance of 250 meters.

Comment: @Eligauthier: For the record this is what a better answer looks like!

Comment: I intend to put more than fifteen g in my next novel. That's why I asked to know the "breaking point". The power is to "stack" gravity (he augment gravity toward a surface) From what I understand, I should justify it by saying he uses an already attracting center to multiply the it's influence (eg. a planet or centrifugal habitat), becoming a catalyst of that center. Since he would use that gravity from a distance and increase it, it would be impossible to generate fusion or a black hole (because he distorts gravity but doesn't incarnate the mass himself).

Comment: I don't actually know enough of the math to write an answer I'd be confident in, but I would still caution that it's probably going to give some fairly inaccurate results to manipulate classical equations (specifically those for g) in order to try to reach a conclusion about a inherently relativistic phenomenon. For an accurate answer, you'd probably have to consider the metric tensor, and the math would get nasty pretty quickly.

Comment: Although I'm not sure offhand, I suspect it's not reasonable to say that relativistic effects don't matter much. A black hole is exactly the type of situation where relativistic effects completely overwhelm their non-relativistic counterparts.

Answer (score 6):

There is no real way to define such a value.

Black holes are so called because at any radius below the Event Horizon the escape velocity (the speed you need to go to not fall back in) is equal to the speed of light.

The problem is that the formula for escape velocity includes M - a mass. To be a black hole you must be massive (as in have some mass).

Your induced ‘black hole’ doesn’t have mass: it’s just a force being created by the guy.

So: what force could be considered to be ‘black holey’ enough?

The first option is choosing a force great enough to overcome neutron degeneracy pressure. This pressure is what stops neutron stars from collapsing to form black holes, so if your hero creates a force great enough that any mass he catches will be pulled in with more force than the forces keeping its neutrons apart then it will very quickly make a teeny tiny black hole. The exact value of this force depends on the properties (temperature, spin, charge, what have you) of the mass being dragged in. The lowest bound *mass* required to beat neutron degeneracy pressure (given that real physics doesn’t have induced gravitational fields) is the wonderfully named Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff limit (2.17 solar masses), but it’s safest to say your man will have to be throwing down a point of gravity equal to that of 2-3 solar masses. The exact ‘g-force’ felt will vary depending on distance from that point, but it’s pretty intense.

For example: a kilometre away you’d feel ~13000000000000 g...

The second (worse) option comes from the equivalence of mass and energy. Theoretically ramming enough energy in one spot is equivalent to having a mass in that same place (hooray for string theory). Your ‘hero’ could create an energetic enough event that the energy involved just spawns a black hole, but it would require more energy than I can even ballpark and would probably lead to the term ‘naked singularity’ being used more than once.

Really I think you don't really want black holes unless you also want to be tearing up the planet you're standing on: It would be better to work out what kind of force you want to exert over what distance and work backwards from there. Even a gravitational point with mass equal to that of the Earth would crush you to indefinable paste if it were right next to you instead of 6300 km under your feet.

TLDR: don’t define it in terms of g forces, define it in terms of what mass of object your guy is simulating the gravity of. Then it’s about 2-3 solar masses.

EDIT TO DISCUSS SIZE:

Black holes don't have a size. They are singularities: Thoroughly unpleasant mathematical constructs where all mass is concentrated into a single dimensionless point. The *event horizon* (where you can't see past) can have a radius.

If we use Event Horizon as the measure of size then since this gravity-bender is making gravitational fields without any mass he will be making a sphere in open space that light cannot escape. Everything he does is creating ludicrously small black holes.

Making a black hole big enough for the event horizon to be visible requires a large enough 'mass' that it will destroy absolutely everything nearby, leaving nobody around to see it.

Needless to say this is Not A Good Idea.

EDIT FOR 'added g':

If all your hero is doing is increasing gravity locally then he is doing one of three things:

1: Telekinetically pushing people towards the ground (not really gravity based)

2: 'Multiplying' gravity worldwide

3: 'Multiplying' gravity locally

I'll ignore 1. It's boring.

2 would have consequences for everyone on the globe all the time, and I'm going to assume your hero isn't going to apply bone crushing force to innocents, so let's discount that.

3 has some very interesting consequences before you even get to black hole status (pushing the Earth out of orbit, for one), but lets ignore those and try focus on the question:

The question doesn't make sense any more. Black holes are points. If this power is a gravity multiplier (which is functionally the same as adding gravity) then the only 'point' a black hole could start to form is the centre of the Earth. Essentially the ground would have to collapse in a column centred on wherever this man was exercising his power, with more and more earth falling into the hole as it progressed. For a black hole to happen our 'Hero' would have to crush the entire mass of the Earth into a ball no larger than it's Schwarzschild Radius, which stands at a stupendously tiny 1.4 x 10<sup>-27</sup>m, in the process destroying everything he ever loved.

Oddly though, the moon, satellites and folks in the ISS would carry on orbiting as normal, so that's something.

Comment: The naked singularity would be a great explanation for aesthetically reasons (the battle scenes could be seen). But generating 2-3 solar mass... I can't think how I'm supposed to justify that. (The hero can generates about 10-15 g at the end of the novel, which is terribly strong)

Comment: @EliGauthier: 10-15g where, though? 10-15 g is just another way of saying '98-147N of force', or 'reasonably telekinetic'. If he's making gravitational fields then closer to the source of the gravitational field that force will be stronger, further away it will be weaker and everything in-between will feel the force too.

Comment: @EliGauthier And don't forget that gravity acts in all directions and doesn't stop for anything. If he's exerting 10g of force on someone 20m away (trying to pull them towards him) he's also exerting 10g of force on the person standing right next to him (pulling them away from him). Gravity is a fickle mistress, unless you just treat it like telekinesis and lose all the intricacy.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to explain something. The gravitational field he generates his constant (eg. 10 g everywhere). The mass of the character doesn't count. The gravity don't crush people on him, but on the ground. It's more like an added g to the environment.

Comment: @EliGauthier: So always pointed towards the centre of the Earth? If that's the case then the concept of black holes just doesn't make sense...

Comment: Exactly. I understand the contradictions. The answers gave me I lot of ideas to create new variations of the power. I'll think about it. Thanks.

Comment: @EliGauthier: Generally it's best to leave accepting an answer for a while. It's entirely likely that someone will turn up with a better answer. :D

Comment: The induced black hole would have the mass of the object being "crushed". For a human mass black hole, that mass is 70ish kilograms, One would expect the size (Schwarzschild radius) to be on the order of an uncompressed atom, and the effects on the surroundings to include localized  intense radiation from initial formation and final dissloution. The life expectancy of such a black hole would be a fraction of a second

Comment: @JoeBloggs hahaha thanks for the advice. I just thought it was a good conclusion. Let's see if someone can gives me more thinking material ;)

Comment: @pojo-guy: Other side effects (if the human was crushed by gravity in the first place) include turning pretty much everything nearby into an accretion disk.

Comment: And by 'nearby' I mean the planet.

Comment: The gravity exerted of a 70 kg black hole is no different than that of a 70 kg man. The accretion disk would not be that large, and at most might extend the life of the black hole by a few milliseconds

Comment: @pojo-guy: the force required to crush the man down into a black hole, though, would very definitely have to beat electron degeneracy, so if it behaves as gravity then the man end everything around him would be subjected to the kinds of forces that would turn everything into an accretion disk, or, more accurately, a smear.

Comment: @JoeBloggs  Yup, which is why I'm of the opinion that if he overextends himself to do this, it means he really has no understanding of what his superpower really is. We already know that it isn't gravity because it does not affect everything universally, so it's something else

Comment: @pojo-guy Indeed. The discussion make me aware I must define the power more accurately. I need to multiply the weight of the people in the area of effect so they : get exhausted fast, get struck lying on the ground suffocating, or at worst, feel their bones break and their organs crushed.

Answer (score 0):

A micro black whole is theoretically possible it would look like a distortion of light and the center would be the tip of a pin. It would do mass devastation if present for a fraction of a millisecond leaving a perfect circle in the Earth. Like a inward sucking bomb. The sudden appearance and disappearance would splatter anything organic near it. Then there is the electromagnetic field with a black hole.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole

Comment: I like the image :) But would it also need a 2-3 solar mass? (I've reed your link and it's seems so). In that case it's difficult to find how the hero could do such a feat.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole : In principle, a black hole can have any mass equal to or above the Planck mass (about 2.2×10−8 kg or 22 micrograms).[2] To make a black hole, one must concentrate mass or energy sufficiently that the escape velocity from the region in which it is concentrated exceeds the speed of light.

Comment: But if I need to create a black hole (like your example where I create a perfect circle in the earth) of about 10 meters radius, I imagine the planck mass become exponentially high ?

Comment: The Planck mass is the smallest possible unit of mass for a real object in our universe.  A 10 meter radius black hole would be disruptive to the solar system, and Earth would have a really Bad Day as it shattered and became an accretion disk. Oh, and a lot of people would be very upset.

Comment: Hahaha ok I see. It's too powerful to be used like how I intended to. Thanks.

Comment: @pojo-guy The Planck Mass is /not/ the smallest possible mass for a real object in our universe.  As you mention in your previous comment, it's about 22 micrograms.  There are objects visible to the naked eye (such as a human egg cell, ~4 micrograms) with less mass than that. Planck Units are about derivation, and there's usually no boundary on the universe set by their value.

Comment: @notovny so a black hole could be smaller than 10 meters?

Comment: @EliGauthier after thinking about what a pea size black hole would do in a fraction of a second everything being pulled into it after it disappears would leave a pile in the center of rubble instead of a crater. Objects effected would be in motion and rest inside the gravity well area. much would pass the center resting  on the opposite side.

Comment: @Muze Theoretically? Yeah, much smaller. An event horizon 10 meters in radius is about three Jupiters, and you /really/ don't want something like that near the Earth, as Pojo-Guy mentions. One the mass of the Earth gets an event horizon of about 0.8 cm radius.  Black holes with human-scale masses have other issues, though; they wind up rapidly evaporating from Hawking Radiation, and turn their mass into energy in very short and unpleasant disorder.

Comment: Hey Muze, just wanted to let you know that we have a [Sandbox on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where you can post question drafts first before posting on the main site. Some regulars try to help people there who sometimes struggle with their posts on main or who simply feel that their draft still needs some work. Just to let you know that this exists and that it might help you.